# Align text in flex container

Tags: css, flexbox

Does anyone know how I can get all the h4s in this pen to align?  I'd like all the icons to be on the same line, and also the h4s to start on the same line as well.  I've tried messing with the flex baseline property but no luck.

Each flex item has this css:

```
.grid-item {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

https://codepen.io/jpaul1982/pen/RwBypMj

Comment: Don't you get the desired result if you remove `justify-content: space-between;` and `align-items: center;` from `.block-grid`?

Comment: Ah, yes I do.  I also just changed the align-items to baseline and got the same result.  Thank you!

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your codepen , you need to change the `block-grid` to

```
.block-grid {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  gap: 5%;
}
```